# Setting Environment Variable for nginx and Rails consumption

Tags: nginx, environment-variables

Apache's module mod_env offers a handy way of setting environment variables in configuration files, like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName xyz.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/rails_app/public
  PassengerAppRoot /var/www/rails_app
  SetEnv MY_VARIABLE contents
</VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html#setenv

However, in nginx I couldn't find anything that serves the same purpose. What's the alternative here? I thought of setting environment variables in .profile files (I am using Ubuntu 10.04), but that wouldn't have the same "per vHost" isolation I have with Apache, right?

What are the alternatives here?

Answer (score 1):

[FastCGI Param](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_param) for fastcgi passing or [Proxy Set Header](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule#proxy_set_header) for when proxy passing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a launcher script that sets the needed enviroment variables before it calls nginx or rails .. and have one scipt per instance?

Answer (score 0):

fastcgi_params will allow you to set environment variables easily. Here's an example of adding environment variables using fastcgi params with php-fpm:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MY_VARIABLE     contents;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```